# Display a pop-up window with status message of a succeeded workflow

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I've a form which runs a real-time workflow. When the workflow succeeds, I need to display the status message of the workflow in a pop-up window or an alert message box.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can only show messages to the user from within a synchronous workflow if you [cancel the workflow](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531057.aspx#BKMK_SynchronousWorkflows):

> When you set the status to canceled, you prevent the operation. An
>   error message containing the text from the stop action status message
>   will be displayed to the user with the heading Business Process Error.

There is no way of showing an informational message from a succeeded workflow.

As a workaround, you could have the workflow write your informational message to a field on the entity. You could then write JavaScript that checks if the message-field contains data, show a [form notification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327828.aspx#Anchor_7) (or an alert if you insist) to the user, and subsequently clear the message-field.