# Display alert from a custom workflow activity

Tags: dynamics-crm, workflow-foundation, dynamics-crm-2015, workflow-activity

Is there a way to show an alert(Message box) from a C#-based custom workflow activity? I'm calling the custom workflow activity from a workflow process

Comment: This is very similar to your other question about displaying alerts from a workflow (though this question is about workflow activities and the other is about workflows, the difference is non-existent): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38094589/display-a-pop-up-window-with-status-message-of-a-succeeded-workflow

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that your workflow is synchronous, otherwise when would the alert appear and to whom?  Doesn't really matter though, sync or async, showing an alert from a custom wf assembly is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show a message to a user (presumably an error message?) then use a syncronous plugin.

If the plugin throws an exception then the user will see this (and the transaction will roll back).