# Where in the logs is the Status Message of the Background (async) workflow Stop step?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I have a background workflow that ends with a Stop step. This step has an optional Status Message attribute that I populate with some details I need to be logged.

After the workflow has run I can find the workflow Status Reason (="Succeeded") and other details in the corresponding System Job record. I would also expect to find the stored info in the Message field, but it's not there. I've tried static and dynamic Status Messages, but no success with neither.

Does anybody know where that message is stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the Message in Details section of System Job is a placeholder for some useful error message/logging tracker to log with the help of `ITracingService.Trace` by developer or by platform when something breaks/exception captured.

The status reason is not the [good place](https://www.crmug.com/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?GroupId=121&MID=9288&tab=digestviewer) for logging `success` scenario message, rather for `canceled` scenario to [pop custom message](https://crmtipoftheday.com/94/cancel-workflow-in-style/) to user & rolling back the transaction.

Not sure why you want to store there, but [better use a custom field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38094589/display-a-pop-up-window-with-status-message-of-a-succeeded-workflow) or even a note (annotation) can help you in better way. Avoid storing successful workflow execution logs anyway.

Comment: More details... I have a workflow that "re-parents" some child records. I wanted a positive confirmation that the workflow was executed, because previously I've had workflows silently failing due to ownership issues. This is mostly for troubleshooting, so I don't want to add a new field for this purpose. One could argue that the success message should be stored somewhere, once I updated it in the Success step. The thing is that I don't find it anywhere.

Comment: @Vic probably you can use output parameter if you want. For troubleshooting you can go & see the set/view properties window for the value of status reason.

Answer (score 1):

Check in system jobs:

[image]

Also, uncheck this value:

[image]

Then, you could try running the workflow sync. I prefer this than waiting for the async service.